# How to stop a Task.Delay() if a value is not kept for the delay time

Tags: c#

So I have a method that when a certain value is above a chosen limit, calls a delayed function.
When such value goes back below the limit I don't want the delayed function to be called anymore and instead calls a different function.

```
public async void DataWasReceivedAsync()
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    if (windSpeed < 3)
    {
        HideData();
    }
    else
    {
        if (tas > 40 && attitudeRoll > 3 || tas > 40 && attitudeRoll < -3)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), tokenSource.Token);
            tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ActivateGoldArrow();
        }
        else if(tas < 40)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            ActivateGoldArrow();
        }
        else
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            ActivateGreenArrow();
        }
    }
}
```

So even if I change the value after the alloted time the ActivateGoldArrow() function gets called anyway.
What have I got wrong?

Comment: You do not check the value after the delay, but only before.

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded?

Comment: It is a multi-threaded program, but thanks to Klaus Gütter I understood where the problem was. As the above mentioned code was a method, every time it was called it created a different cancellation token source, thus making it impossible to pass the tokensource.Cancel() to the task.delay.